# Change all assets location on build and correct routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, iis, vue-router

I want to have a Vue app for just one page (Home/Index) inside an existing MVC asp.NET website, but the routing is not working as I expected.

The existing asp.NET is inside c:/inetpub/wwwroot/bar/app/ on the server and I placed the files from Vue's 'dist' folder on the same place.

I've also changed the index.cshtml from the view of the asp.NET app that I want to point to the Vue app so that it contains what is necessary to call the scripts generated by Vue.
But the problem is, when I access www.foo.com/bar/app, it changes the URL to www.foo.com/

I've tried changing in `vue.config.js` the property `baseURL: '/bar/app'` (the vue app was on 2.9) for it to understand that it's inside that folder on the server. Then I tried to upgrade vue to 3.8 and use the property `publicPath: '/bar/app'` but to no avail.

I've also tried changing the configuration of the router in the `router.js` file to include `base: 'bar/app'` and still got the same results.

There's also this guide for configuring IIS for Vue that I followed: [Hosting Vue JS SPA build on Microsoft IIS](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hosting-vue-js-spa-build-microsoft-iis-zainul-zain).

When I try with `yarn serve` it works correctly but when I put inside my local IIS with the same folder structure it doesn't

I'm pretty sure my problem might be solved by using relative paths, but I think that I tried every changing every one of them and still could not get the correct result.

router.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from 'vue-router'

const CadastrarRoteiro = () => import('@/views/Roteiro/CadastrarRoteiro.vue')

export default new router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/bar/app', //process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/CadastrarRoteiro',
      component: CadastrarRoteiro
    },
    // Admin Pages
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Layout,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'bar/app/CadastrarRoteiro',
          component: CadastrarRoteiro
        },
      ]
    },
    // Not found route
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
})
```

vue.config.js

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
// const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  publicPath: '/bar/app/',
  // baseUrl: '/bar/app/', // !!!ORIGINAL!!!: process.env.VUE_BASE_URL || '/',
  //   outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './bar/app'),
  //   assetsDir: './', //path.resolve(__dirname, './bar/app'),
}
```

index.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "";    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <base href=/ >
    <link rel=icon href="~/favicon.ico">
    <title>Form</title>
    <link href="~/js/chunk-2d21aba5.ff8c6269.js" rel=prefetch>
    <link href="~/js/chunk-89ad2c08.00c8a8e5.js" rel=prefetch>
    <link href="~/css/app.e2f3077d.css" rel=preload as=style>
    <link href="~/css/chunk-vendors.8f8bf103.css" rel=preload as=style>
    <link href="~/js/app.bb762d9c.js" rel=preload as=script>
    <link href="~/js/chunk-vendors.fe1112ee.js" rel=preload as=script>
    <link href="~/css/chunk-vendors.8f8bf103.css" rel=stylesheet>
    <link href="~/css/app.e2f3077d.css" rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but this app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script src="~/js/chunk-vendors.fe1112ee.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.bb762d9c.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to access the website's home page in www.foo.com/bar/app and get the vue component 'CadastrarRoteiro' but also stay with the same URL instead of changing the URL to www.foo.com/

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have any url rewrite rule in asp.net site and vue app?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal The link I provided explains about installing an extensio called 'IIS URL Rewrite' and also adding a few tags on the `web.config` file. I tried without doing this first and then after, but nothing changed (except that, with the tags, the other routes of the asp.NET stopped working)

Comment: try to put "." instead of "~" in the path.